# How to Generate a C# Event Handler Stub from Visual Studio 2012 Source view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Many times the signature of a control's event handler isn't obvious.  Currently, in order to generate an event handler stub in the code behind I have to

1. Leave **Source** view and enter **Design** view (and wait for the UI to be generated)
2. Click on the control in question (which sometimes isn't obvious)
3. Open the Properties toolbar
4. Click on the lightning bolt
5. Double-click on the event for which I want to generate a stub

Is there an easier way to do this while still in Source view?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you wanting us to tell you how to make VS2012 read your mind to understand which control you're wanting to generate an event for and which event it is you want to handle for that control?

Comment: Well, inasmuch as intellisense reads your mind I guess.  If I were to declaratively add the **OnClick="butSubmit_Click"** property to a button control, I think the editor would then know which event I want to generate and for which control.  Seems like at that point there could be an automated way to generate the event stub in the code-behind (maybe the button is a bad example because the signature is simple).  I know in VB you can use the dropdowns at the top of the page in the code-behind to generate event stubs for any controls so it seems like this should be possible in C#.

Comment: Found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068680/keyboard-shortcuts-for-creating-event-handler-stubs-in-visual-studio) which hints 3rd Party plug-in was required to accomplish this in Visual Studio 2008.